# Sorting lines from longest to shortest

Tags: bash

How can I rearrange all of the lines in a file from longest to shortest? For e.g.:

```
elephant
zoo
penguin
```

Would be changed to

```
elephant
penguin
zoo
```

Comment: The example is a bit misleading, if you don't go back to read the question.  To sort list of words, longest to shortest, adapt the acceptable answer e.g. `pip search json |awk '{print length($1)"\t"$1}' |sort -rn |cut -d' ' -f2-`.  Obviously "pip search json" is just there to produce output instead of a filename.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Add the line length as the first field of the line, sort, and remove the line length:

```
awk '{ print length($0) " " $0; }' $file | sort -r -n | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

Comment: why the cat? [UUoCA](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: @Fredrik: I like to have the filename in front of my pipelines. You have the nicer award, though, so I have fixed it.

Comment: can be shortened to `$ awk '{print length"\t"$0}' File | sort -rn | cut -f2-` which is basically the same thing except that cut operates on tabs per default so ignore this :-)

Comment: @Fredrik Your shorter version that uses tabs as delimiter instead of the space character has the negative side effect that the tab is printed first. Command `$ awk '{print length"\t"$0}' tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt` outputs ` "$0}' tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt2 AC`etc... Using the longer version without tabs generates safer terminal/command output. At least when running in bash version 3.2 on Mac OS X 10.7.5.

Comment: @thiton: You can put the filename at the front without using `cat`, like this: `< input_file command1 | command2 | commmand3 > output_file`

Comment: I'm using the similar way to find the first `build.gradle` by using: `find $PWD -name "build.gradle" | awk '{print length($0), $0 | "sort -n"}'  | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2-`

Answer (score 4):

TIM (my terse version for TIMTOWTDI... hmm but now it's long already :(

```
perl -ne '@a = <>; print sort { length $b <=> length $a } @a' file
```

lets reserve `reverse` and `push` when needed

and I wonder how long it would take on that 550MB file

Comment: The 550MB file took 14.2 seconds on perl 5.24

Answer (score 2):

Perl version, with a tip of the hat to @thiton:

`perl -ne 'print length($_)." $_"' file | sort -r -n | cut -d ' ' -f 2-`

`$_` is the current line, similar to awk's `$0`

perl-5.24 execution on a 550MB .txt file with 6 million lines (British National Corpus) took 24 seconds

---

@thiton's awk (3.1.7) execution took 26 seconds

---

With a tip of the hat to @William Pursell from a related post:

`perl -ne 'push @a, $_; END{ print reverse sort { length $a <=> length $b } @a }' file`

perl-5.24 execution took 12.0 seconds

Answer (score 1):

With POSIX Awk:

```perl
{
  c = length
  m[c] = m[c] ? m[c] RS $0 : $0
} END {
  for (c in m) q[++x] = m[c]
  while (x) print q[x--]
}
```

[Example](//github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/112a40f/bash/.bashrc#L39-L49)