# How to sort the lines in a file from shortest to longest?

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

Similar to [Sorting lines from longest to shortest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296649/sorting-lines-from-longest-to-shortest), how can I sort all of the lines in a file from shortest to longest? E.g."

```
This is a long sentence.
This is not so long.
This is not long.
```

That becomes:

```
This is not long.
This is not so long.
This is a long sentence.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's almost exactely the same as in the link you gave

```
awk '{ print length($0) " " $0; }' $file | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

the `-r` option was for reversing the sort.

Answer (score 6):

```
perl -ne 'push @a, $_ } { print sort { length $a <=> length $b } @a' input
```

(On my box, this runs about 4 times faster than the `awk | sort | cut` solution.)

Note that this uses a terrible perl idiom and abuses the semantics of `-n` to save a few keystrokes.  It would be better to write this as:

```
perl -ne '{ push @a, $_ } END { print sort { length $a <=> length $b } @a }' input
```

Comment: +1. More like 7.5 times faster when tested on a 200+K logfile. The `asorti` solution was terminated because it took too long, not sure why it's so inefficient.

Comment: Followup question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815105/how-does-this-perl-one-liner-in-the-bash-works

Comment: Probably you should not confuse users, and write `perl -ne 'push @a, $_ ; END { print sort { length $a <=> length $b } @a }'` instead...

Comment: @Slaven, I agree!  Unfortunately, this -p while/loop braces hack is common enough in perl...will edit with proper disclaimers.

Comment: I benchmarked several solutions on a 550MB text corpus, and found that using pure perl results in a 6x speedup, vs Perl + pipes to shell commands.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296649/sorting-lines-from-longest-to-shortest/33511642#33511642

Answer (score 1):

**Note that this solution does not perform well on large input.**

You could also do the sorting within `awk`:

```
cat << EOF > file
This is a long sentence.
This is not so long.
This is not long.
EOF
```

*sort.awk*

```awk
# Only find length once
{ len = length($0) }     

# If we haven't seen this line before add it to the lines array 
# and move on to next record
lines[len] == "" { lines[len] = $0; next }

# A duplicate, append to the previous record
{ lines[len] = lines[len] RS $0 }

END {
  # lines array is sorted according to the indices, the sorted
  # indices are stored in the indices array
  asorti(lines, indices)
  for(key in indices)
    print lines[indices[key]]
}
```

Run like this:

```
awk -f sort.awk file
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
< file awk '{ len = length($0) } lines[len] == "" { lines[len] = $0; next } { lines[len] = lines[len] RS $0 } END { asorti(lines, indices); for(key in indices) print lines[indices[key]] }'
```

Output:

```
This is not long.
This is not so long.
This is a long sentence.
```

Answer (score 1):

With POSIX Awk:

```perl
{
  c = length
  m[c] = m[c] ? m[c] RS $0 : $0
} END {
  for (c in m) print m[c]
}
```

[Example](//github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/d0cf984/bash/.bashrc#L28-L37)

Answer (score 1):

Another perl implementation:

`perl -ne 'print length($_)." $_"' file | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f 2-`

`$_` is the current line, similar to awk's `$0`