# How does this perl one liner in the bash works?

Tags: linux, perl, bash

I was looking on how I could sort a file based on the length of each sentence and I came across this snippet from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417403/how-to-sort-the-lines-in-a-file-from-shortest-to-longest)

```
perl -ne 'push @a, $_ } { print sort { length $a <=> length $b } @a' input
                      ^ ^
```

I tested it and it works but I don't have a clue how this works! As far as I can see the syntax is wrong. It has an open right bracket and a non closed right bracket which I have marked.
I am really having trouble figuring out how to run perl commands like this in bash
Could some one please explain this snippet?

Answer (score 10):

`}{` is so called butterfly or [**Eskimo greeting**](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Eskimo_greeting_%7d%7b) Discovered by Abigail, in 1997.

Basically it closes `while` loop imposed by `-n` switch, and what follows `}{` is block executed after while loop.

This is how perl parses this line,

```
perl -MO=Deparse -ne 'push @a, $_ } { print sort { length $a <=> length $b } @a' input
```

---

```
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    push @a, $_;
}{ # <==here it is

    print((sort {length $a <=> length $b;} @a));
}
```

A more common way would be using [**`END{}`**](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2c-UNITCHECK%2c-CHECK%2c-INIT-and-END) block instead of `}{` operator:

```
perl -ne '
  push @a, $_ 
  END { 
    print sort { length $a <=> length $b } @a
  }
' input
```

Comment: That's a nice link, although they have a mistake in there. The eskimo kiss does not work with the `-p` switch, only `-n`.

Comment: @TLP yes, `-p` has `continue` block so it doesnt work properly

Answer (score 5):

SzG's answer is correct: the script works because the `-n` switch causes Perl to *literally* wrap the code in the following loop:

```
LINE: while (<>) { # code goes here
;}
```

before compiling it.  Thus, your example code becomes:

```
LINE: while (<>) { push @a, $_ } { print sort { length $a <=> length $b } @a
;}
```

which is a perfectly valid Perl script.

---

Anyway, a less hacky way to write that script would be:

```
perl -ne 'push @a, $_; END { print sort { length $a <=> length $b } @a }' input
```

or even just:

```
perl -e 'print sort { length $a <=> length $b } <>' input
```

Comment: Shouldn't the array `@a` be declared?

Comment: @Jim: We're not in [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) mode, so no, it's not necessary. Of course, for anything longer than a one-liner, you do want to `use strict` and declare your variables properly.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen:Still.The { push @a, $_ } is in the while scope so we read and push until EOF.But why does the print ` print sort { length $a <=> length $b } @a` is a loop?I run this line in a separate script like this: my @a=(5,6,2,3,7); print sort { length $a <=> length $b } @a; and it did not print the array sorted

Comment: @Jim: Please don't post your comments twice. Also, you should really ask a new question about that (if you can't figure out the answer yourself; hint: what's the sort block sorting by?) instead of posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

You run a Perl script specified on the command line with the `-e script` option.
If you also add the `-n` option, Perl will surround the script with a

```
while(<>) {
    your-script-here
}
```

loop that reads standard input of the specified files line by line.

Comment: @Jim: It works because Perl _literally_ wraps your code in a `while (<>) { ... }` loop when you use the `-n` switch. So the actual code executed becomes `while (<>) { push @a, $_ } { print sort { length $a <=> length $b } @a }`.

Comment: `@a` is not declared anywhere.Shouldn't it be?

Comment: You don't need to declare stuff in Perl. They just spring to life when you use them.