# How to get a list of TLD's using bash for building a regex?

Tags: regex, bash, tld

In the need for finding e-mail addresses and host names, we would like to improve an existing regex to seach only for **existing public TLD's**.

We would like one bash command where we can copy and paste its output into our **regular expression**.

We already had trial with (co|com) which matches only 'co' and doesn't match the full 'com' tld for .com domains, that is why the tld list need to be sorted with **longest TLD's first**.

Can someone supply a one line "copy and paste" **bash command** that outputs the most recent list of TLD's sorted and formatted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of @Alex_Volkov his answer in [Regular expression to match DNS hostname or IP Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106179/regular-expression-to-match-hostname-or-ip-address/2375080#2375080) we were pointed to http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt is source for TLD's.

With the help of @thiton his answer in [Sorting lines from longest to shortest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296649/sorting-lines-from-longest-to-shortest#answer-8296668) the output could be sorted so that the longest TLD's are listed first.

Resulting in this one liner:

`$ curl -s http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt | sed '1d; s/^ *//; s/ *$//; /^$/d' | awk '{print length" "$0}' | sort -rn | cut -d' ' -f2- | tr '\n' '|' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed 's/\(.*\)./\1/'`

that nicely outputs the desired TLD regex part:

`xn--clchc0ea0b2g2a9gcd|xn--hlcj6aya9esc7a|xn--hgbk6aj7f53bba|xn--xkc2dl3a5ee0h|xn--mgberp4a5d4ar|xn--11b5bs3a9aj6g|xn--xkc2al3hye2a|xn--80akhbyknj4f|xn--mgbc0a9azcg|xn--lgbbat1ad8j|xn--mgbx4cd0ab|xn--mgbbh1a71e|xn--mgbayh7gpa|xn--mgbaam7a8h|xn--9t4b11yi5a|xn--ygbi2ammx|xn--yfro4i67o|xn--fzc2c9e2c|xn--fpcrj9c3d|xn--ogbpf8fl|xn--mgb9awbf|xn--kgbechtv|xn--jxalpdlp|xn--3e0b707e|xn--s9brj9c|xn--pgbs0dh|xn--kpry57d|xn--kprw13d|xn--j6w193g|xn--h2brj9c|xn--gecrj9c|xn--g6w251d|xn--deba0ad|xn--80ao21a|xn--45brj9c|xn--0zwm56d|xn--zckzah|xn--wgbl6a|xn--wgbh1c|xn--o3cw4h|xn--fiqz9s|xn--fiqs8s|xn--90a3ac|xn--p1ai|travel|museum|post|name|mobi|jobs|info|coop|asia|arpa|aero|xxx|tel|pro|org|net|mil|int|gov|edu|com|cat|biz|zw|zm|za|yt|ye|ws|wf|vu|vn|vi|vg|ve|vc|va|uz|uy|us|uk|ug|ua|tz|tw|tv|tt|tr|tp|to|tn|tm|tl|tk|tj|th|tg|tf|td|tc|sz|sy|sx|sv|su|st|sr|so|sn|sm|sl|sk|sj|si|sh|sg|se|sd|sc|sb|sa|rw|ru|rs|ro|re|qa|py|pw|pt|ps|pr|pn|pm|pl|pk|ph|pg|pf|pe|pa|om|nz|nu|nr|np|no|nl|ni|ng|nf|ne|nc|na|mz|my|mx|mw|mv|mu|mt|ms|mr|mq|mp|mo|mn|mm|ml|mk|mh|mg|me|md|mc|ma|ly|lv|lu|lt|ls|lr|lk|li|lc|lb|la|kz|ky|kw|kr|kp|kn|km|ki|kh|kg|ke|jp|jo|jm|je|it|is|ir|iq|io|in|im|il|ie|id|hu|ht|hr|hn|hm|hk|gy|gw|gu|gt|gs|gr|gq|gp|gn|gm|gl|gi|gh|gg|gf|ge|gd|gb|ga|fr|fo|fm|fk|fj|fi|eu|et|es|er|eg|ee|ec|dz|do|dm|dk|dj|de|cz|cy|cx|cw|cv|cu|cr|co|cn|cm|cl|ck|ci|ch|cg|cf|cd|cc|ca|bz|by|bw|bv|bt|bs|br|bo|bn|bm|bj|bi|bh|bg|bf|be|bd|bb|ba|az|ax|aw|au|at|as|ar|aq|ao|an|am|al|ai|ag|af|ae|ad|ac`