# grep valid domain regex

Tags: regex, bash, dns, grep

I'm trying to make a regex for grep that match only valid domains.

My version work pretty well but match the following invalid domain :

```
@subdom..dom.ext
```

Here is my regex :

```
echo "@dom.ext" | grep "^@[[:alnum:]]\+[[:alnum:]\-\.]\+[[:alnum:]]\+\.[[:alpha:]]\+\$"
```

I'm working with bash so I escaped special characters.

Sample that should match :

```
@subdom.dom.ext
@subsubdom.subdom.dom.ext
@subsub-dom.sub-dom.ext
```

Thanks for help

Comment: In case there is a need to exactly grep and match only existing tld's, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460680/how-to-get-a-list-of-tlds-using-bash-for-building-a-regex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**A truly complete solution requires *more work***, but here's an ***approximation* that may work well enough** (note that a `@` prefix is assumed and the input string is expected to start with it):

```
^@(([a-zA-Z](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*)\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}$
```

You can use this with `egrep` (or `grep -E`), but also with `[[ ... =~ ... ]]`, bash's regex-matching operator.

Makes the following assumptions, which are more permissive than actual DNS name constraints:

- Only ASCII (non-foreign) letters are allowed - see below for Internationalized Domain Name (IDN) considerations; also, the Punycode *(ASCII-compatible) forms of IDNs - e.g., `xn--bcher-kva.ch` for `bücher.ch` - are not matched - see below.
- There's no limit on the number of nested subdomains.
- There's no limit on the length of any label (name component), and no limit on the overall length of the name (for actual limits, see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/04/12/10292868.aspx)).
- The TLD (last component) is composed of letters only and has a length of at least 2.
- Both subdomain and domain names must start with a letter; subdomains are allowed to be single-letter.

Here's a quick test:

```
for d in @subdom..dom.ext @dom.ext @subdom.dom.ext @subsubdom.subdom.dom.ext @subsub-dom.sub-dom.ext @x.org; do
 [[ $d =~ \
    ^@(([a-zA-Z](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*)\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}$ \
 ]] && echo YES || echo NO
done
```

---

**Support for [Internationalized Domain Names (IDN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) with *literal* Unicode characters** - again, a complete solution requires more work:

A simple improvement to also match IDNs is to replace `[a-zA-Z]` with `[[:alpha:]]` and `[a-zA-Z0-9]` with `[[:alnum:]]` in the above regex; i.e.:

```
^@(([[:alpha:]](-?[[:alnum:]])*)\.)+[[:alpha:]]{2,}$
```

**Caveats**:

- ***No* attempt is made to recognize [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)-encoded versions of IDNs**, which use an ASCII-based encoding with prefix `xn--`, and which would require decoding afterwards.
- As [Patrick Mevzek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6368697/patrick-mevzek) points out, the above **can yield both false negatives and false positives** (using his examples):

  - False positive: an *invalid* Punycode-encoded name such as `ab--whatever`
  - False positive: Invalid cross-language names; e.g., `cαfe.fr`, which uses a Greek letter in a French domain name - a rule that is impossible to enforce via a regex alone.
  - False negatives: emoji-based names such as `.ws` (`xn--jr8h.ws`)
  - False negative: `பரிட்சை` is a valid TLD in IANA root today, but will not match `[[:alpha:]]{2,}$`
  - ... and many more
- Not all Unix-like platforms fully support all Unicode letters when matching against `[[:alpha:]]` or `[[:alnum:]]`. For instance, using UTF-8-based locales, OS X 10.9.1 apparently only matches Latin diacritics (e.g., `ü`, `á`) and Cyrillic characters (in addition to ASCII), whereas Linux 3.2 laudably appears to cover all scripts, including Asian and Arabic ones.
- I'm unclear on whether names in right-to-left writing scripts are properly matched.
- For the sake of completeness: even though the regex above makes no attempt to enforce length limits, attempting to do so with IDNs would be much more complex, as the length limits apply to the *ASCII* encoding of the name (via [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)), not the original.

<sup>Tip of the hat to @Alfe and for pointing out the problem with IDNs, and to @Arka for offering a simplified version of the regex to replace the lengthier one I had initially crafted under the mistaken assumption that single-letter domain names must be ruled out.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "@dom.ext" | grep -E "^@[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-.]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*.[a-zA-Z]+$"
```

This did the job.

Comment: domains can start with numbers?

Comment: Also, you need to escape the last occurrence of `.`.

Comment: @Alfe, yes, `3com.com` is a valid domain name. That restriction on not starting with a number was removed long ago from DNS specifications.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
grep '@[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]\-]*\.[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]\-]*\.[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]\-]*$'
```

Comment: You assume 3 components (subdomains), but the OP also wants to match domains (2 components). Also, aren't TLDs composed of letters only (.com, .info, ...)?

Comment: Yeah, right.  But when going into such details we also could consider the unicode domains (things like www.müller.de), then [a-z] also would not be enough and I fear that the `[[:alnum:]]` of `grep` would maybe also handle those umlauts incorrectly (depending on codecs etc.).  So I guess we can leave it the way it is with your accepted answer; if that works for the OP, it should be enough.  If however he wants to have a definitive answer, I think none of ours would be enough yet ;-)

Comment: Good points, thanks. I've updated my post and provided at least some answers and have also clarified limitations of my solution.

Comment: This has the same problem as @mklement0 for IDNs, it will have many false positives and false negatives.