# domain name regular expression not matching

Tags: regex, shell, sh

I have a shell script at /www/cgi-bin/test that I can access on my network at `http://192.168.1.1/cgi-bin/test`.

I am attempting to parse the query string, which should look like `d=domain.com`, and validate it against a regular expression:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

domain=${QUERY_STRING#d=}

if [[ ! $domain =~ [A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,}) ]]; then
    exit
fi

echo "Validation success!"
```

When this didn't work, I tried using another regex which I stole from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21172644/1015595):

```
if [[ ! $domain =~ \
    ^(([a-zA-Z](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*)\.)*[a-zA-Z](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$ \
]]; then
    exit
fi
```

I can't get this regex to match either. In both cases, I tried escaping the curly braces (`\{2,\}`) according to the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html), but that didn't make any difference.

In case it's relevant, the platform I'm on is OpenWrt 12.09.

Edit: I just realized my shell script might not support bash's `[[ ... =~ ... ]]` syntax. Unfortunately OpenWrt doesn't ship with bash.

Comment: it would be simpler and more portable if you used a case statement and glob match instead of those pita to read bashisms.

Comment: Please post a code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have `bash`, and/or you cannot replace the shebang with `#!/bin/bash`, then the `[[` expression might not work, or the pattern substitution with `${QUERY_STRING#pattern}` might not work.

In that case, you can use `awk` to hit two birds with one stone:

```
if ! echo $QUERY_STRING | awk '$0 !~ /^d=[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$/ {exit 1}'; then
    exit 1
fi
```

Or, if the pattern substitution works, and only the regex doesn't then you can use `expr` instead of `awk`:

```
domain=${QUERY_STRING#d=}
if ! expr $domain : '[A-Za-z0-9-]\{1,\}\(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]\{1,\}\)*\(\.[A-Za-z]\{2,\}\)$' >/dev/null; then
    exit 1
fi
```

In both cases, I used a bit more strict pattern for the `d=` in the `QUERY_STRING`. In both cases, be careful to end the pattern with a `$`, otherwise things like `domain.com-` would pass.

Comment: Now that I've pulled all my hair out I can confirm the pattern substitution does indeed work while the `[[ ... =~ ... ]]` syntax does not. Your solution using `expr` did the trick, but please escape the plus signs. (So... much... ESCAPE.) Also thanks for the tip about ending with `$` - otherwise `google.c` passed.

Comment: In fact `+` and `\+` don't work on my system, so I used `\{1,\}` instead which works, and I just forgot it at one place, thanks for pointing out! In any case I recommend the `awk` solution instead of `expr`, if you have `awk`

Answer (score 2):

Your regex looks fine but problem appears to be in your string manipulation of populating variable `domain`.

You need to replace:

```
domain=${QUERY_STRING#d*=}
```

by

```
domain=${QUERY_STRING#?d=}
```

Which will give you: `domain.com` in `$domain`

**UPDATE:** You have wrong shebang `#!/bin/sh`

You need to have:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

**UPDATE 2:** You can do this in `sh` (non bash) to get your desired value:

```
QUERY_STRING='d=domain.com'
domain=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | awk -F'd=' '{print $2}'`
echo "$domain"
domain.com
```

To validate you can use `egrep`:

```
echo "$domain" | egrep -q '[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})'
```

Comment: Wait, I don't see any difference.

Comment: My mistake, bad copy/paste. Fixed it now

Comment: Actually no, the revised code populates the variable with `d=domain.com`, which is not what I want.

Comment: That is not correct. `#?d=` will strip out `?d=` part and will leave `domain.com` as the variable's value.

Comment: Run this command to test: `bash -c 'QUERY_STRING='?d=domain.com'; echo ${QUERY_STRING#?d=}'`

Comment: I can verify the test command produces the desirable output, but for some reason it doesn't in the shell script. I replaced everything after `echo ""` with `echo ${QUERY_STRING#?d=}`, which printed `d=domain.com` on the page. However `echo ${QUERY_STRING#d*=}` printed `domain.com` without the `d=`.

Comment: Because you have `#!/bin/sh` shebang. You need to have `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: OpenWrt doesn't ship with bash. It's all busybox. I guess that means I can't use those bash inline replacements, huh? Also my title is misleading.

Comment: @anubhava the `QUERY_STRING` doesn't contain the `?` mark. The definition of `QUERY_STRING` is the part of the url *after* the `?` mark.

Comment: @janos: I just went by this line from OP `I am attempting to parse the query string, which should look like ?d=domain.com`

Comment: My mistake. Still, the regex is not matching even after fixing the replacement.